# Border exchange in cartesian topology mpi

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I would like to perform border exchange in my mpi programm.
I have structure which look like that :

```
cell** local_petri_A;

local_petri_A = calloc(p_local_petri_x_dim,sizeof(*local_petri_A));

for(int i = 0; i < p_local_petri_x_dim ; i ++){
        local_petri_A[i] = calloc(p_local_petri_y_dim,sizeof(**local_petri_A));
    }
```

where cell is :

```
typedef struct {
  int color;
  int strength;
} cell;
```

I would like to have an exchange scheme like on this picture :[image: border exchange in cartesian topology]

So i put my program in a cartesian topology and first define mpi type to perform the exchange :
void create_types(){

```
////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////
// cell type
const int    nitems=2;
int          blocklengths[2] = {1,1};
MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
MPI_Aint     offsets[2];

offsets[0] = offsetof(cell, color);
offsets[1] = offsetof(cell, strength);

MPI_Type_create_struct(nitems, blocklengths, offsets, types, &mpi_cell_t);
MPI_Type_commit(&mpi_cell_t);
////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////

MPI_Type_vector ( x_inside , 1 , 1 , mpi_cell_t , & border_row_t );
MPI_Type_commit ( & border_row_t );
/*we put the stride to x_dim to get only one column*/
MPI_Type_vector ( y_inside  , 1 , p_local_petri_x_dim , MPI_DOUBLE , & border_col_t );
MPI_Type_commit ( & border_col_t );
```

}

and then finally try to perform the exchange from south and north:

```
   /*send to the north receive from the south */
   MPI_Sendrecv ( & local_petri_A[0][1] , 1 , border_row_t , p_north , TAG_EXCHANGE ,& local_petri_A [0][ p_local_petri_y_dim  -1] , 1 , border_row_t , p_south , TAG_EXCHANGE ,cart_comm , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
   /*send to the south receive from the north */
   MPI_Sendrecv ( & local_petri_A[0][ p_local_petri_y_dim  -2] , 1 , border_row_t , p_south , TAG_EXCHANGE ,& local_petri_A [0][0] , 1 , border_row_t , p_north , TAG_EXCHANGE ,cart_comm , MPI_STATUS_IGNORE );
```

NB: in this section x_inside and y_inside are the "inside" dimension of the array (without ghost part) and p_local_petri_dim are dimensions of the full array.

Then i have this error :[image]

Is there something that i've done wrong ?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in the way you allocate your 2D array.
You allocate an array of arrays, so two rows are unlikely in consecutive memory. As a consequence, your ddt for a column does not match your 2D array layout.

You can refer to [MPI_Bcast a dynamic 2d array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104847/mpi-bcast-a-dynamic-2d-array/5107489#5107489) to allocate your array correctly.

As a side note, Fortran does not have this kind of problem, so if this is an option, that would make your life easier.

Comment: Ok so it will not work for the column but what about the row ? here i only try to send some row and i have still an error, with my allocation row are contiguos in memry aren't they ?

Comment: rows are definitely contiguous. Please edit your question with a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and i will have a look at it

Comment: I noted you sendrecv with `& local_petri_A [0][ p_local_petri_y_dim  -1]`, should it be `& local_petri_A [p_local_petri_y_dim  -1][1]` instead ?